# Копирование значений одного объекта в другой [JS]

Tags: javascript, frontend

Есть два объекта, с равным количеством свойств.

Пример первого (заполненного):

```
{
  "subject": {
  "title": "Title (definition of type of object)*",
  "classification": {
    "scheme": "Sheme",
    "id": "Sheme code*",
    "description": "Sheme name*"
  },
  "description": "Short description*",
  "period": {
    "startDate": "Start date*",
    "endDate": "End date*"
  }
}
```

Пример второго (пустого):

```
{
  "class": {
    "title": "",
    "classification": {
      "scheme": "",
      "id": "",
      "description": ""
    },
    "description": ""
  },
  "planning": {
    "budget": {
      "period": {
        "startDate": "",
        "endDate": ""
      }
    }
  }
```

Никак не могу скопировать значения с первого и подставить их во второй.

Уточню, процесс должен быть автоматизирован. Просто руками захардкодить - не вариант.

Comment: Object.assign, lodash.clone или велосипед строить

Comment: С чем конкретно возникли затруднения? Почему никак не можете, что вы пробовали?

Comment: Мне необходимо скопировать значения из первого объекта во второй, именно значения, без копирования объектов.

Comment: конечным результатом должен быть второй объект со значениями первого. Пример class.title = subject.title ("Title (definition of type of object)*")